# Restrict Characters in Datagridview Cell

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, c#-2.0

I have a column which is of integer.
when i edit this cell,i need to enter only numbers but not characters.
Am not using datagridviewTextboxColumn.It is a cell.
It should not allow typing characters just like a textbox_keyPress event where we give Char.IsDigit to restrict characters.

How do i do this in C# ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about C# winforms, then you just need to build your own DatagridViewColumn class. Microsoft have a sample showing how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180996.aspx - luckily for you, they happen to be showing how to build a masked text box!

You might also need to take note of: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d0029092-f1ff-4e54-9e01-8fb189c7474c/

Answer (score 0):

Server-side checking is straightforward. For client-side, I would recommend JQuery Masked Input plug-in. Check this out: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

You'll have to attach the event programmatically though.

PS: This is the 3rd time (I think) I've recommended this solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

For client-side you can use JQuery, but if you need a quick solution just use asp.net Validators (Specifically CompareValidator)

Comment: Client-side validation won't work. The user can simply turn Javascript off in their browser to circumvent the validation. Client-side validation should only be used *to complement* server-side validation as a help for the user. It should not replace it.

Comment: That depends on the situation and the purpose of the application. Of course that public applications you should add also a server side validation. But that's much easier to implement...